# How to find Size of SwiftUI Font

Tags: ios, swiftui

Is there a way to get the size of SwiftUI Font. For example, I would like to get the size of Font.body = 17, size of Font.callout = 16, etc.

I am looking for something similar in UIKit where you can find the size of a UIFont. See https://gist.github.com/zacwest/916d31da5d03405809c4

Looking at the other posts on stackoverflow.com and other places, there is no direct conversion from SwiftUI Font to UIFont.

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Im looking for an answer to the same question. I have a Font defined in SwiftUI, how can I get the size of that font programmatically? To reuse for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Human Interface Guidelines outline the size of Dynamic Type sizes like `body` and `callout` [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/).

Given this, I'm fairly certain SwiftUI and UIKit sizes are equivalent.

Comment: thanks for the link. Is there a way to programmatically find the size of the font. I know this is a dynamic font

Comment: Also, I am aware of the sizes but was wondering if there is a way to find the size in my view code